# bootstrap accordion works like two collaspe separate

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I've made a accordion but the two collapse work separatly. I hope to have : when i click on a title, the open one is closed, but here the opened doesn't close..
Wher is my fault ?

```
<div class="accordions_container">
<div class="accordion" id="accordions_491">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordions_491"
            href="#accordion_title_toto491">accordion title toto</a>
        </div>
        <!-- .accordion-heading -->
        <div id="accordion_title_toto491" class="accordion-body collapse in">
            <div class="accordion-inner">Content of the accordion here</div>
            <!-- .accordion-inner -->
        </div>
        <!-- .accordion-body -->
    </div>
    <!-- .accordion-group -->
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading"><a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordions_491"
            href="#accordion_titi491">accordion titi</a>
        </div>
        <!-- .accordion-heading -->
        <div id="accordion_titi491" class="accordion-body collapse ">
            <div class="accordion-inner">Content of the accordion here</div>
            <!-- .accordion-inner -->
        </div>
        <!-- .accordion-body -->
    </div>
    <!-- .accordion-group -->
</div>
<!-- .accordion -->
```

Comment: do you have any javascript associated with the accordion?

Answer (score 0):

The provided markup works as intended on jQuery 1.8.2, BS 2.1.1.

Maybe other scripts are interfering.